Why would a home have two water softeners in series?
I am purchasing a house that runs on well water.  The system has two water softeners (exact same units), each with a digital controller on it and one salt tank.  I am familiar with the basic system--I installed my own in my last house--but I can't figure out why they would need two.  The house is only 3 bedroom and two baths.  They are in series as well.
Does anyone know why a basic house would need two?  It also has a chlorinator on it, as there is a problem with a sulfur smell.  It is in rural Florida, where iron can also be a moderate problem.
The softeners are Gold series by Culligan.

Have you asked the seller why there are 2 softeners in series? I'd agree that it's extremely unusual. Only thing I can think is that IF they sense hardness of outgoing water before cycling, then the 2nd softener won't do anything until the first one runs out of salt, effectively making for a longer period between having to reload salt. This, however, is a BIG IF and a SWAG - I've never heard of anyone doing that. Most (that I'm aware of) base the recharge cycle on water flow, not any hardness sensing.

The person that was living there died, His sister is selling it.  It seems like an expensive move just for less salt regen!  Only other thing is Colligan sold him a bill of goods.

That was really just a random guess - I haven't a clue why someone would do this.

@Grim, please don't mark questions with [Solved]. Take the [tour] to learn how to respond to answers (or provide your own).

I have equipment that looks like two water softeners and one salt tank, but the salt tank is only hooked up to the second unit. The first unit is an iron filter containing Birm media, not water softening resin.
The iron filter -- which looks just like a water softener -- uses a water softener head that is programmed to backflush every X days, but there is no "regeneration" or salt uptake in its cycle. It backflushes for 10 minutes, then does a forward flush for one minute to repack the media, and that's all.
The actual water softener takes an hour and 20 minutes for its regeneration cycle.
Have a look at the salt tank and check to see if the tubing from the tank goes to just one of your units or if it has a T arrangement to supply both. If it goes to only one unit, you probably have an iron filter and a water softener.
Another possible explanation: you have a chlorinator and I assume a contact tank, so the other "softener" could be a granular carbon filter to remove the chlorine. That could also look just like a water softener. It would backflush on a schedule to drive the chlorine out of the carbon. I had one of those in a previous house. Note that if you have radon in the water, carbon filters become very radioactive over time, so "hot" that they must be handled as hazardous waste.
You can call the local Culligan office and ask them. They have records on what was installed at your property.

You are right the first tank in the system doesn't have a line to the salt tank, only the second tank.    The chlorinator feeds to a large tank and then to the softeners and then out to the house.  I think it is to help remove bacteria and the sulfur smell.

@Grim It's also possible that the first device that looks like a softener contains a mixture of Birm for iron reduction and granular carbon to remove the chlorine residue, so the original owner wouldn't need yet another "softener" setup. Best to contact Culligan anyway for instructions on chlorine replenishment and dilution. If you do it wrong, you can damage your softener ($$).

A spot of googling on "why have two water softeners" shows that there are such things as "twin tank" setups: two separate softener resin tanks and one brine tank.
Normally, a single-resin-tank softener is programmed to regenerate at a time when it is unlikely that hard water would be drawn into the plumbing. This is usually after midnight. However, while regenerating, the softener cannot soften, and hard water can get through if water is used during the regeneration process.
Having two resin tanks means, when one tank is regenerating, the other is softening water. Thus one would theoretically never have a time when hard water can run in the pipes. Folks who have round-the-clock human activity in their location might need such a setup.
Either the previous owner really needed to never under any conceivable circumstances get hard water, or someone bought more equipment than they needed.

I did google but all the two tank systems don't have two digital controllers, just one.  That is why this is weird to me.

Yes this is all true but irrelevant to the OP’s situation. Two-tank systems (I have one) have only one controller, so that it can guarantee alternating between tanks.
